# Как спарсить данные с атрибута data-url тега tr (python)?

Tags: python, html, парсер, beautiful-soup, теги

Мне нужно спарсить данные с data-url, чтобы получить ссылку на подстраницу сайта (использую *beautifulsoup* и *requests*). Я пишу так: `ssilka = soup.find_all ('data-url')`, но получаю пустой список (т.е. это **[]** ).

Вот фрагмент HTML кода сайта:

`<tr class="statistic-table__tr___3O1oy" data-url="/city-ratings/gelendzhik-c923"><td class="statistic-table__td___2SXmY statistic-table__td1___30ZsU">Геленджик</td><td class="statistic-table__td___2SXmY statistic-table__td2___23eDp statistic-table__activeCol___2B-H1">1</td><td class="statistic-`

Ссылка на сайт: https://www.domofond.ru/city-ratings

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssilka = [x.get['data-url'] for x in soup.find_all ('tr')]
```

Comment: Спасибо, мне это помогло! Единственное, 'data-url' написал в круглых скобках, в квадратных получал ошибку.